# How to stop apps, like Techsmith's Snagit, from opening popups

Tags: malware, popups

So, I'm busy working.  Focused and productive, using my favorite tools, and all of a sudden a pop-up opens advertising TechSmith webinars.  I've no browsers open so I was surprised and disturbed.  A couple clicks around revealed that it was spawned by Techsmith's Snagit app.

I've heard that Window's users often suffer from malware apps that spawn advertisements in similar ways, but this is a first for me on OS X.

Is there a way to stop apps from being able to spawn pop-ups?  I don't want to delete the app, but it's unacceptable to disrupt work like that.  It would be great if there was some system-wide OS configuration that would stop app developers from being able to spam.

[image]

Comment: Is this the free trial, or the paid version?  What have you tried already to disable them?  Have you tried contacting TechSmith about it yet?  In general, you can't stop running apps from opening windows.

Comment: Is that a paid version of the app?

Answer (score 1):

A great app for catching these things is [little snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html).

Since you've already figured out that it is SnagIt causing this I would check with them. https://feedback.techsmith.com

O haven't seen this problem using the paid version on the Mac. There is also a setting in the preferences to turn off notifications from TechSmith which might solve it for you.

When you figure out a solution please come back and share.  G'luck!

- Stephen

Answer (score 0):

I found it was attached to AVG or Avast, almost as a false reading, to get you to sign up for their trial subscription, as it didn't find any issues, during pop-up attacks otherwise. But the second I opted in for the trial, the pop-ups suddenly went away. This is not to say AVG or Avast was directly responsible, but when I installed Norton, Trend Micro and Kaspersky, none of them seemed to detect any the pop-up issues AVG and Avast did. Sus.